# How to delete only one category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove one main category from the URL.

Example of links that are now:

1. [www.site.com/cat1/item1](http://www.site.com/cat1/item1)
2. [www.site.com/cat2/item2](http://www.site.com/cat2/item2)

I want to delete only "cat2" from the url. To make it so:

1. [www.site.com/cat1/item1](http://www.site.com/cat1/item1)
2. [www.site.com/item2](http://www.site.com/item2)

```
add_filter( 'post_link', function($a){
    return str_replace( 'cat2/', '', $a );
}, 99 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox to the left of each category name allows you to select the categories you want to remove. When all of the categories you want to delete have been selected, choose Delete from the Bulk Actions menu, and then click Apply. The categories are being deleted.